# Needed example of a docker run --user on a windows server running docker

Tags: docker

On my windows server 2016, I am trying to figure out the run command syntax to run a docker image as a user in my ldap.  I read this [article](https://medium.com/@mccode/understanding-how-uid-and-gid-work-in-docker-containers-c37a01d01cf), but I am not following it very well (different environments)

Perhaps I am miss understanding the concept all together, but in the end I need to run the container as a specific user in our active directory.

**Any links to a well documented run --user examples would be appreciated...**

One of the things that is confusing is trying to figure out the UserId and such...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer depends on the use case, but may be gMSA authentication would help? Basically, with gMSA authentication, you can add the host OS to an AD domain, and containers running on it can share the privileges to use things like network drive.  That way, you don't need to pass credential every time you access them.

MS team has a good write up on it here:

Active Directory Service Accounts for Windows Containers
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/manage-serviceaccounts

Also, artisticcheese has fantastic walk through.

Enabling integrated Windows Authentication in windows docker container
https://artisticcheese.wordpress.com/2017/09/09/enabling-integrated-windows-authentication-in-windows-docker-container/

Hope this helps.